# Responsive design code for list view

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to design a responsive web page that lists out items with links and description like the one on dzone newsletter view https://dzone.com/pages/daily-example
The page is expected to be compatible with both web and mobile.

What technology can I use? Can I do this with css and html?

Comment: Use Bootstrap CSS framework , it is responsive , get more detail here : http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: you can use bootstrap making responsive layout : https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do layout like this with HTML and CSS, using a framework or from scratch. Concerning dynamic design, you should research and understand relative vs. absolute units in CSS, as well as best practices surrounding usage for each.

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned, bootstrap would fit nicely (see the grid section)

http://getbootstrap.com/

You can also use some css to create breakpoint according to the size of your screen.
Here is one done with `sass` (http://sass-lang.com/):

```
@mixin breakpoint($class) {
  @if $class == xs {
    @media (max-width: 767px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $class == sm {
    @media (min-width: 768px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $class == md {
    @media (min-width: 992px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $class == lg {
    @media (min-width: 1200px) { @content; }
  }
  @else if $class == xlg {
    @media (min-width: 1367px) { @content; }
  }
  @else {
    @warn "Breakpoint mixin supports: xs, sm, md, lg";
  }
}
```

You then use it this way :

```
div {
   width: 100px; // on mobile
   @include breakpoint(sm) { // tablet an bigger
      width: 200px; 
   }

}
```